# Insert characters in a string using python

Tags: python, insert, character

Here is what I am trying to achieve: I want to replace

```
void some_function(int,  int *, float);
```

with

```
void some_function(int a, int *b, float c);
```

So far, I have tried to replace "," with chr(97+i) as I loop through the string.

```
text = len("void some_function(int,  int *, float);")
i = 0
for j in range(0, length)
    if text[j] == ",":
       rep = " " + chr(97+i) + " .,"
       text = text.replace("," rep)
       i = i + 1
       j = 0 # resetting the index, but this time I want to find the next occurrence of "," which I am not sure
```

But this is not doing the job. Please let me know if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: You are trying to refractor C code with python?

Comment: I am new to python, not sure how to go about this! :(

Comment: If you are trying to refactor generic code, it's a very non-trivial task.  Think about cases where the function arguments span more than one line.  Cases with 0 or 1 argument (no commas).  How about `void other_function(void)` where you don't want a variable name?

Comment: If you are refactoring C code, I think you are better off doing this with a good code text editor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

i = 96
def replace(matches):
    global i
    i += 1
    return " " + chr(i) + matches.group(0)

re.sub(',|\)', replace, "void some_function(int,  int *, float);")
```

Comment: Nice answer, but it should be noted this will only work once, since i is global.  After that you'll get d,e,f,g...until it explodes.

Comment: I don't know C, but I was wondering, isn't it a problem that there's a space between * and b in the result?

Comment: @BrtH: Nope: `int* b`, `int *b`, `int * b`, and even `int*b` are valid

Answer (score 1):

```
text = "void some_function(int,  int *, float);".replace(',', '%s,') % (' a', 'b')
```

Answer (score 0):

The original idea does not work, since the last parameter is not followed by a ',' but by a ')'.

```
import re
import string

def fix(text):
    n = len(re.findall('[,(]', text))
    return re.sub('([,)])', ' %s\\1', text) % tuple(string.letters[:n])
```

Comment: Correctly answers the OP's very specific case, but still fails for things like `fix('joefunc()')` and `fix('joefunc(void)')`.  Not a dig on the answer, just a note for the OP.